# How specific are duplicates?

Tags: discussion

How are questions "related" enough to become duplicates ?

I made this question

[Accepting questions in other languages](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16631/are-questions-in-other-language-other-than-english-accepted-in-au)

An it is being marked as duplicate but I find that it is not. I'm asking about *accepting* answer and the duplicate is about *handling*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on the users voting on the definition of "duplicate," which is why this is a democratic process.

By definition, however, it means that the general question you've asked have already been asked and answered, and the answer for the given question *should* work for you.

If the duplicate target does *not* answer your question, you may edit your question to make it sufficiently different, or point out *why* the duplicate target does not answer your question. Optionally, you may appeal your case on meta, where the community at large (or one of our <s>gods</s> moderators) will decide on your case.

In your specific case, both questions are essentially asking "What does this site do with non-English posts?" As such, your question was closed as a duplicate, because the target answered your question as to whether foreign-language posts are accepted *and* how to deal with them.