# Edited a question, but it doesn't display my name

Tags: support, editing

I edited a question (translated from Italian to English) and my name wasn't shown on the post. Then in my two and a half hours later I noticed that someone else's name is displayed there. How is that possible? How does that work? I got 2 points for editing though.

Answer (score 5):

Because you currently have less than 2000 reputation, your edit was not applied immediately and was instead sent to a queue to be peer reviewed by other users (who have at least 2000 reputation).

Someone [reviewed your edit suggestion and chose to **Edit** it](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1213157). That means that when they were presented with your suggestion in the queue, they chose the option to **Improve** the suggestion, which has these effects:

- the reviewer is presented with the post in the editor with the suggested changes applied, and can edit it however they see fit
- the edit suggestion is "approved" when the reviewer finishes their additional edit
- the suggester receives +2 reputation
- [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398268/revisions) shows both edits, as separate revisions
- the reviewer is considered to be the more recent of the two editors and so their name and avatar are displayed in the *last edited by* spot immediately, **so the suggester's name and avatar are never shown there**. If the edit is simply approved by reviewers without further changes being made, then the suggester's name and avatar will be displayed.*

By the way, please see [this post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19894/is-translating-posts-using-google-translate-acceptable) - we actually don't want such edits to be done.

*<sub>Different rules apply to a rare type of post called a Community Wiki, which can be edited by any user with at least 100 reputation points. For those posts, the name of the last editor is not displayed at all, and the person who has contributed the most to the post will be shown as the author. The post you edited is not a Community Wiki.</sub>

Comment: You're welcome Joepie Es :) @Someone thanks for fixing my mistakes... I read the post a few times and didn't pick them up at all... kind of worrying!

Comment: @Zanna Me neither, hahaha, I clicked on the edit button to check the markdown and Grammarly started complaining about the typos :)